# 'eurostat' R package does not save .rds files

Tags: r

I usually download bulk datasets from the Eurostat using the `get_eurostat()` function from the `eurostat` package present on the CRAN. Until recently it worked perfectly well, however not long ago I noticed it stopped downloading the datasets into `.RDS` files despite `cache = TRUE` in the function parameters.

```
# install.packages("eurostat")
library(eurostat)

datasets <- c("demo_fordagec")

for (i in datasets) {
  
  temp <- get_eurostat (i, 
                        cache = TRUE, 
                        update_cache = TRUE,
                        cache dir = "c: /users/ropia/oneDrive/Dokumenty")
  }
```

The above code indeed creates a data frame called `temp`, but does not create .RDS file in the cache_dir as it used to before. This happens regardless of what destination folder I choose.
What could be the reason?

My R is 4.2.3 and the 'eurostat' package is obviously updated to the newest version.

Comment: Side note. The loop overrides `temp` in each iteration. Is this intentional?

Comment: There have been some quite major recent changes to the eurostat package to cope with changes in the underlying API – do any of the changes listed at https://ropengov.github.io/eurostat/news/index.html#eurostat-3714-2023-02-22 explain the issue?